# Reading line by line does not work

Tags: perl, hash, while-loop, split

I have a file like this

```
key1 value1
key2 value2
key3 value3
```

etc.

I want to create a hash from this by splitting each line on white space. I have tried like this

```
while (<FILE>) {
  chomp;
  my ($key, $val) = split / /;
  $hash{$key} .= exists $hash{$key} ? ",$val" : $val;
}
```

this gives the output

```
key1 => value1, key2
```

and the rest of the lines are ignored.

When I checked if reading it line by line worked, it did not.

It does not read line by line but instead the `while` loop loops only once with all the data.

Why does it do this?

Comment: @user3353408: If you want to split `$_` on any combination of whitespace then you need the default behaviour of `split`, so `my ($key, $val) = split;` is probably better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are appending `.= ",$val"` to each hash value regardless of whether it existed previously, because `$hash{$key} .=` *implicitly creates* the element `$hash{$key}` so that it can receive the assignment. That means `exists` will always return *true*, and only the first branch of the conditional will ever be evaluated. This happens for any array or hash element

Your example data is wrong because it contains no equals signs `=`, but what I think you mean is to append `",$val"`to the hash values only if they already contain data. If there is no element corresponding to `$key` then you just need to assign `$val`

Like this perhaps

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %hash;

while (<DATA>) {
  chomp;
  my ($key, $val) = split /=/;
  if ( exists $hash{$key} ) {
    $hash{$key} .= ",$val";
  }
  else {
    $hash{$key} = $val;
  }
} 

use Data::Dump;
dd \%hash;

__DATA__
key1=value1
key2=value2
key3=value3
key1=value4
key2=value5
```

**output**

```
{ key1 => "value1,value4", key2 => "value2,value5", key3 => "value3" }
```

---

**Update**

If you *really* want to do this in a single line (although I recommend that you don't) you just need to replace `exists` with `defined` in your code, giving

```
  $hash{$key} .= defined $hash{$key} ? ",$val" : $val;
```

because, although the element is auto-vivified and so *exists* it still has no value until it receives its first value, so is still not *defined*

But please use the simple `if` statement so that the vagaries of auto-vivication don't complicate things for people who must maintain your code

---

**Update**

Here's another way

```
$hash{$key} .= ',' if exists $hash{$key};
$hash{$key} .= $val;
```

Both this and the standard `if` work properly because the condition is tested *before* the `.=` operator is evaluated. It is only when the assigned value uses a conditional expression that the `.=` is executed first

Comment: Curious. `$hash{$key} .= exists $hash{$key} ? ...` behaves differently than `$hash{$key} = $hash{$key} . exists $hash{$key} ? ...` .

Comment: @mob: Then we are in `perlbug` land and you should report it. Do you have code that demonstrates the problem? I will happily raise a report if you would rather not

Comment: `perl -E 'say $x{y}.=exists $x{y}'` vs. `perl -E 'say $x{y}=$x{y}.exists $x{y}'`

Comment: @mob: That's neat and pretty comdemning. Will you raise the bug or shall I?